# xgboost with tree_method = 'hist' in R

Tags: r, xgboost, kaggle, lightgbm

According to a benchmarking of GBM vs. xgboost vs. LightGBM (https://www.kaggle.com/nschneider/gbm-vs-xgboost-vs-lightgbm) it is possible to implement xgboost with the argument

```
tree_method = 'hist'
```

in R.

However doing so gives me always an error:

```
Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
Invalid Input: 'hist', valid values are: {'approx', 'auto', 'exact'}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your full code so this can be better reproduced? Thanks!